# DataTables - child rows not working when using Datetime-moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datatables

I've managed to get this into live.datatables.net and almost working, except I cannot get the last detail to display as a child.

The last  in the rows  should be displaying with the "Message Info:" - yet I cannot figure out how to get that Detail to show up.  The issue I'm trying to solve is the current DataTable isn't having the Date sort correctly - so using the "datetime-moment.js" plugin allows the date to be sorted correctly, but has "broken" how the "hidden" child is working.  I've gotten it this far, yet I'm stumped of how to get the "Message Info" to display.

For example, the first "TR" has the "TD" of "raUni=71421861,action=U,beqUni=1700538,rateCode=F-BAIT" - when the user clicks the "Show/Hide Extra Info" link, it should open up each row with "Message Info: raUni=71421861,action=U,beqUni=1700538,rateCode=F-BAIT".

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Michael

http://live.datatables.net/yavoradu/5/edit

Comment: If you are following an example, i would like to see a link to it. You are trying to insert a div between tr's. That is improperly formatted html.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out your issues and made some changes as well.
I removed all of the divs you put in since they are not valid html.
In your format function, you never define the data columns so d.msgInfo does not exist. The data for the row is in an array, so in my modified code, its d[15].

Just for fun, I added a column for the buttons for expanding individual rows.
Also, I removed your link at the top and replaced it with the button at the bottom of the table.

http://live.datatables.net/bovonodi/1/edit

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(
    { "columnDefs" : [ { "targets" : -1, "visible" : false, "name" : 'msg_info'} ],
    "iDisplayLength" : 15,
    dom:'tBp',
    "aLengthMenu" : [ [15, 25, 50, 100, -1 ], [ 15, 25, 50, 100, "All" ] ],
    "order" : [ [ 2, "desc" ] ],
    columns:[    {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },null, null, null, null, null, null,
          null, null, null, null, null, null,
          null, null, null],
    buttons:[{text:'Show Info', action:function(e, dt, node, config){

       if(node[0].innerText == "Show Info"){
          node[0].innerText = "Hide Info";
          hideShowExtraInfo(true);
       }
       else { 
            node[0].innerText = "Show Info";
            hideShowExtraInfo(false);
        }
   }}]

});


$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );
    var td = $(this);

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        td.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        td.addClass('shown');
    }
} );

} );


function hideShowExtraInfo(doShow) {
      var table = $('#example').DataTable();
      table.rows().every(function() {

          console.log("Temp");
          var tr = $(this.node());
          var td = tr.children(".details-control");

          if (!doShow) {
          // This row is already open - close it
              this.child.hide();
              td.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              // Open this row
              this.child(format(this.data())).show();
              td.addClass('shown');
          }
      });
  }

 function format(d) {

      // `d` is the original data object for the row
      return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'
        + '<tr><td>Message Info:</td><td>'
        + d[15]
        + '</td></tr></table>';

  }
```